# Basic app with Toolbar works just once

Tags: codenameone

I'm very new to CodenameOne, and I'm developing an app with a toolbar menu. It works just the first time, I click the menu entry and when I come back to the main class toolbar stops working until I rotate or stop/resume the app.

Thank's in advance.

My code:

```
public class FDRMobileApp {

    private Form current;
    public static Form hi;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {

        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        hi = new Form("FDR", BoxLayout.y());

        Toolbar tb = hi.getToolbar();
        tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Home", FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, e->{});
        tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Orari e Turni", FontImage.MATERIAL_MEMORY, e-> new OrariTurniForm(theme).show());
        tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Contatti", FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO, e-> new ContattiForm(theme).show());
        tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Dove siamo", FontImage.MATERIAL_MAP, e-> new MapForm(theme).show());

        hi.show();  

    }

    public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }

    }

    public void destroy() {              
    }
}
```

And a Form:

```
class MapForm extends Form {

    public MapForm(Resources theme) {
        super("Dove siamo");

        getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> {
            FDRMobileApp.hi.showBack();
        });        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the current update due to the [switch to the on-top menu](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pixel-perfect-on-top-menu.html). We'll release an update later today which should fix the navigation issue in the app.

Comment: It should be up now